# Merge rows together by condition in R

Tags: r, merge

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
IsLead    ID Path    LogTime                    PathCode    Conversion
0         198822     2015-06-19 01:57:11.000    J           ConvA
0         198822     2015-06-19 01:58:33.000    F           ConvA
1         198822     2015-06-19 02:07:01.000    H           ConvA
0         253547     2015-06-20 07:52:33.000    A           ConvD
1         253547     2015-06-20 07:52:33.000    H           ConvD
2         351754     2015-06-20 07:52:33.000    J           
2         351754     2015-06-20 07:52:33.000    A
```

Where IsLead indicates if a row is going to convert, where 0 is an interaction on the path, and where 1 is the actual conversion point. 2 indicates that the path is not going to convert.

ID Path indicates the unique path. so every path with a 0 has to contain a 1. and every path with a 2 only contains a 2.

LogTime indicates the time for the interaction.

PathCode indicates the type of interaction. where H indicates the interaction where a conversion happens, so IsLead 1 is always PathCode H, and indicates that the ID Path is done.

Conversion indicates at what conversion point that the conversion has happened.

The rowsare sorted to ensure that you follow each ID paths path and they are not intertwining across eachother

I would like to alter my data.frame so it looks like this:

```
ID Path    Lead    Path    Conversion
198822     1       JFH     ConvA
253547     1       AH      ConvD
351754     0       JA
```

So what has happened is that for each ID Path, the PathCode has been merged in the correct order. And for each path with a conversion the LEAD is 1, and 0 if there is no conversion.

If possible I would prefer to have the Path column displayed WITHOUT the "H", so the Path will in this case be: "JF", "A", "JA".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution (I'm assuming the data is already sorted, of not, you can add `order(LogTime)` to the `i`th expression)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Lead = +all(Conversion != ''), 
              Path = gsub('H', "", paste(PathCode, collapse = ""), fixed = TRUE)), 
          by = .(ID.Path, Conversion)]

#    ID.Path Conversion Lead Path
# 1:  198822      ConvA    1   JF
# 2:  253547      ConvD    1    A
# 3:  351754               0   JA
```

Or similarly with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID.Path, Conversion) %>%
  summarise(Lead = +all(Conversion != ''),
            Path = paste(PathCode, collapse = "")) %>%
  mutate(Path = gsub('H', "", Path, fixed = TRUE))

# Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
# Groups: ID.Path
# 
#   ID.Path Conversion Lead Path
# 1  198822      ConvA    1   JF
# 2  253547      ConvD    1    A
# 3  351754               0   JA
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked like a charm!
I have noticed that I actually would prefer to have the Letters in the path in reverse order. Meaning that instead of JF in the first row, that it should be FJ. Are you aware of a function that reverses the order of the letters?
Or would it be possible to just alter the order of the dataframe from the beginning?

Comment: Yes, just replace `paste(PathCode, collapse = "")` with `paste(rev(PathCode), collapse = "")` in both solutions. Or you could order your data in decresing order too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sqldf` library, which ships with the helpful `group_concat` function (available in MySQL):

```
> require(sqldf)
> df_new <- sqldf("select IDPath, case when Conversion = '' then 0 else 1 end as Lead,
                       Conversion, group_concat(PathCode) PathCode
                   from df
                   group by IDPath", method = "raw")
> df_new$PathCode <- gsub("H|,", "", df_new$PathCode)
> df_new
  IDPath Lead Conversion PathCode
1 198822    1      ConvA       JF
2 253547    1      ConvD        A
3 351754    0                  JA
```

The above code assumes your original data frame is called `df`.  Note that I had to manually remove the commas from the `PathCode` column because I could not find a way to get the `SEPARATOR` keyword to work along with R's version of the `group_concat` function.

Comment: Maybe also remove `H` as per their desired output.

Comment: Yes but does he only want to remove a terminal "H" or any "H" which might appear?

Comment: Any `H` as per their desired output "*so the Path will in this case be: "JF", "A", "JA".*"

Comment: Maybe just do it in a single call, something like `gsub("H|,", "", df_new$PathCode)`?